# @Webfilter for duplicate users - not working

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

my Webfilter Code looks like this:

```
@WebFilter(
urlPatterns={"/search.jsp"},
dispatcherTypes= {
    DispatcherType.FORWARD,
    DispatcherType.REQUEST
    },
    filterName="LoggingFilter",
    description="Checks if user already logged in"
)
public class FilterAlreadyLoggedUser implements Filter {


public FilterAlreadyLoggedUser() {}


public void destroy() {}


public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
     HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
     HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
     HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

     if(session.getAttribute("customer") != null){ //If user is already logged in
         response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/alreadyLoggedIn.jsp");
       } else{
            chain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
      }
}


public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {}

}
```

i call this filter bevor a customer should see the search.jsp which includes all the relevant stuff.

So with this filter, i want to check if a customer is already logged in.
But it dosen't work.
Can someone tell me why?

Thanks

Comment: where /when are you setting "customer" as session attribute?

Comment: the session "customer "is set in der SignIn-Servlet . So the User first comes to the login.jsp site where he must set his email address and password. Then, when he clicks "login" the servlet "SignIn" is called and validate the user (with help from MySQL). After that and when the passwort and email is valid the "SignIn" forward to the "search.jsp". Else the requestdispatcher forwarding to a failed.jsp.